# 500 Server Error in PHP

Tags: php

If you visit my script "page.php" in the URL. A 500 Error appears. If you submit through a form it works.

```
<?php
## send forgot pass
$a=$_REQUEST['email_address'];
include("template.funcs.php");
$yz = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("", $yz);
$b=mysql_real_escape_string($a);
$d=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `customers_email` = '".$b."'");
    if (mysql_affected_rows()==0){
        header("Location: cart.php?pass=notsent");
    }else{
        send_registration_email($b,'','','');
        header("Location: cart.php?pass=sent");
    }
mysql_close($yz);
?>
```

Comment: What does your error log tell you? It should detail the exact error the web server encountered. Always look there first.

Comment: Look at your server's error logs. Details of the 500 will be logged there. What you see in the browser is deliberately vague/useless, because 500 errors can reveal internal configuration details that should NOT be made public.

Comment: By the way, _always_ call `exit();`  after a `header("Location...");` to prevent further script execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 500 error is a server side error, and I've found the best way to fix this is to check the logs on your server.

On the other hand, looking at your code, you may not have defined $_REQUEST['email_address']. Try this:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
    ## send forgot pass
    $a=$_REQUEST['email_address'];
    include("template.funcs.php");
    $yz = mysql_connect("","","");
    mysql_select_db("", $yz);
    $b=mysql_real_escape_string($a);
    $d=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `customers_email` = '".$b."'");
        if (mysql_affected_rows()==0){
            header("Location: cart.php?pass=notsent");
        }else{
            send_registration_email($b,'','','');
            header("Location: cart.php?pass=sent");
        }
    mysql_close($yz);
}
?>
```

Comment: This bring up a blank PHP document as expected. However how would I redirect them if email_address is empty.

Comment: If you have not outputted any information yet then you could redirect them with: header('Location: domain.com/page.php');

If you have outputted information then you could output an inline JavaScript to redirect them: window.location = 'domain.com/page.php';

Comment: You could also output a link to allow them to manually redirect if the $_REQUEST['email_address'] is not set.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume this has something to do with `$_REQUEST['email_address']` not being defined on normal page load...

Comment: Would that generate a 500? I would have thought 500 means syntax error in script or unable to compile for some reason.

Answer (score 1):

Use useful variable names. Use indenting appropriately. Only escape input before inserting it into your database. Group often used functionality in functions. Don't use `$_REQUEST`. Fail fast. A few hints which massively increase your code quality.

Now have a look at this:

```
include("template.funcs.php");

function Redirect($to)
{
    header("Location: " . $to);
    exit();
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD' != "POST" || !isset($_POST['email_address']))
{
    Redirect("cart.php?pass=notsent"); 
    // or redirect to your "forgot password" form
}

$mailAddress = $_POST['email_address'];

$dbconn = mysql_connect("","","");
mysql_select_db("", $dbconn);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `customers` WHERE `customers_email` = '".mysql_real_escape_string($mailAddress)."'");

if (mysql_affected_rows() == 0)
{
    Redirect("cart.php?pass=notsent");
}

send_registration_email($mailAddress,'','','');
Redirect("cart.php?pass=sent");
```

Comment: Then start debugging. ;-) See the other answers, you need to configure PHP so that it outputs errors, instead of simply throwing a status 500. And disable "User friendly errors" in IE.